# Splitting string, extracting chars and putting back together

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, text-processing

I have strings in the form of `wva/sia/e1`, `bct/e2`, `sv/de/e11`. It's always  `<Part1>/e<NUM>` or `<Part1>/<Part2>/e<NUM>`. What I want is to shorten the strings by keeping the first letters of the parts and ditching the slashes and e:

```
wva/sia/e1 > ws1
bct/e2 > b2
sv/de/e11 > sd11
```

How can I do that inside an sh script?

Edit: The string represents a job name:

```
[...]
job_name=$1 # e.g. 'wva/sia/e1'
job_name=cut_name(job_name) # e.g. 'ws1'
[...]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the form of a *script* as what you ask for:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

# read the input, split by /
st = sys.argv[1].split("/")
# get the first char of all sections *but* the last one
# add the last *from* the first character
print("".join([s[0] for s in st][:-1])+st[-1][1:])
```

Note that this works for any lenght, e.g.:

```
wva/sia/bct/wva/sia/e1
```

will become

```
wsbws1
```

as long as the last section ends with `/e<num>`

#### To use

1. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `rearrange.py`
2. Run it with the string as argument, e.g.:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/rearrange.py wva/sia/e1

   > ws1
   ```

#### Explanation

The script pretty much explains itself, but also is commented.

Comment: I thought of doing it in bash, but I also can just call that python script. Thanks!

Comment: @user1406177 you're welcome! Not sure if bash is the most handy tool for this :)

Comment: Well, bash can do it,too :)

Answer (score 3):

#### Bash 4.3 One-liner

Let's just say that we don't need a full script. Bash has enough capabilities that allow us to get away with a one-liner. Here's one:

```
bash-4.3$ (read -r var ;IFS='/'; printf "%c" ${var%/*};echo ${var##*[^0-9]}) <<<  "sv/de/e11"
sd11
```

What is happening ?

- everything happens in subshell, hence `( )` around the whole command
- we use here string `<<<` to send input , and the subshell command gets it via `read -r var` and stores into `var` variable
- we set `IFS='/'` so that the subshell breaks `var` into separate items at `/` separator. This is important for word splitting.
- next we use suffix removal `${var%/*}` to get rid of the last part before `/` . In the above example it would be `e11`
- `printf "%c"` will see the result of `${var%/*}` as `sv de` due to word splitting and suffix removal mentioned above (magic, yes). Because of how `printf` words, `%c` will print only first character, but it will do so for each command-line argument it receives, so for `sv de` it will output `s` and `d`.  Printing is done without newline, hence it appears as if characters are typed in sequence
- `echo ${var##*[^0-9]}` makes use of prefix removal to get rid of all non-digit characters in the given input string, thus obtaining only the last digits

---

There's another one-liner approach, which is a bit more explicit and natural to C-like programmers.

```
bash-4.3$ (read -r inp;IFS='/';arr=( $inp ); for ((i=0;i<$(( ${#arr[@]} -1 ));i++));do printf "%s" ${arr[$i]:0:1};done;printf "%s\n" ${inp##*[^0-9]}) <<<  "sv/de/e11"
sd11
```

What is this magic ?  Here's an explanation:

- Everything happens in subshell, hence `()` around the whole command.
- We use here-string `<<<` to send the item we want into command's stdin stream, and the command gets it via `read -r inp` command and stores it into `inp` variable
- Next we change `IFS` variable so that we can break down everything into an array.
- we iterate over all items until the one before last using C-style for loop `for ((initial condition; test condition; post condition)) ; do ... done`
- the `$(( ${#arr[@]} - 1 ))`  is arithmetic expansion where we subtract 1 from the length of the array `${#arr[@]}`
- the `printf "%s" ${arr[$i]:0:1}` allows us to use parameter expansion where we print only first character of each item, and `printf "%s"` prints it without newline, thus it appears like we're printing each letter on the same line.
- finally, once the loop is over, we take original input text and get rid of everything that is non-digit using prefix removal `${#*[^0-9]}`

#### Script approach

Since the question asks for a shell script, here is one in `bash` 4.3 , which is almost the same approach as above, but more explicit:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
IFS='/'
items=( $1 )
counter=1
for i in ${items[@]}
do
    if [ $counter -eq ${#items[@]}  ];
    then
        # note the space before -1
        printf "%s\n" "${i##*[^0-9]}"
    else
        printf "%s" "${i:0:1}"
    fi
    counter=$(($counter + 1)) 
done
```

The way this works is like so:

- given a string on command-line as argument, we set internal field separator to `/` , and allow bash to perform word  splitting to break down the string into array called `items`
- we iterate over all items in the array `${items[@]}` , while keeping track of which item we're at using the counter variable and knowing the number of items in the array (the `${#items[@]}` part).
- The `if-statement` is what allows us to pick specific character from each item. Using parameter expansion, first character via`${i:0:1}`. Using longest prefix removal `${variable##prefix}`, we remove all non-digit characters from the last string in `printf "%s\n" "${i##*[^0-9]}"`.

Here it is in action:

```
$ ./shorten_string.sh "wva/sia/e1"                         
ws1
$ ./shorten_string.sh "bct/e2"                             
b2
$ ./shorten_string.sh  "sv/de/e11"                     
sd11
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, not a script, but you can put it in a script (also this is very inelegant since I failed to deal with both forms in one command)

```
$ sed -r 's:(.).*/(.).*/e([0-9]+):\1\2\3:;s:(.).*/e([0-9]+):\1\2:' file
ws1
b2
sd11
```

#### Notes

- `-r` use ERE
- `s:old:new:` replace `old` with `new`
- `.*` any number of any characters
- `(.)` save one character in this position
- `([0-9]+)` save at least one digit here
- `;` separates commands, like in the shell
- `\1` backreference to characters saved with `()`